# Some codes puzzle me in nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am studying node.js, and I see some codes like this

```
const mysql = require('mysql')
const config = require('./defaults')

var pool  = mysql.createPool({
  host     : config.database.HOST,
  user     : config.database.USERNAME,
  password : config.database.PASSWORD,
  database : config.database.DATABASE,
  port      : config.database.PORT
});

let query = function( sql, values ) {
  return new Promise(( resolve, reject ) => {
    pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        if (err) {
            resolve( err )
        } else {
            connection.query(sql, values, ( err, rows) => {
                if ( err ) {
                    reject( err )
                } else {
                    resolve( rows )
                }
                connection.release()
            })
        }
      })
    })
}

let postdetail = function (id) {
  let _sql = `
      SELECT * FROM posts where postid = ${id}
  `
  return query(_sql)
}

module.exports={
  postdetail
}
```

What puzzles me is that `query` is a function, and it has two parameters, one is `sql`, another is `values`, but in `postdetail`, the `return` only has one parameter, Can someone explain it to me? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`query` is a wrapper function on mysql query function. It takes query and values. It can be used to perform `Select`, `Insert` and `Update` queries of mysql.

Thus in case of select you only need to pass mysql `query`, no need to send values and inside that `query` wrapper method `values` will be `undefined`.

For cases like `Insert` and `Updated` you can send values as array as along with query.